# Autodesk forge SVF2 dbid

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I configured our viewer to use SVF2 format yesterday as per these instructions: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/notes/

I have observed that when selecting a node in the model, we get different Id's from SVF vs SVF2.

I usually pull the metadata and properties using the following GET calls:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

It has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486866/how-to-match-objectids-from-autodesk-model-derivative-api-%20metadata-with-forge-vi/64495956#64495956) that the SVF2 Id's are computed differently, is there a way to get the Id's of a SVF2 model without loading it into the viewer first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologizing for any inconvenience had caused. This is a known issue that our engineering team is evaluating, and we're hearing customers' voices. Could you consider providing your use case to SVF2 objectId with more details and the paint points you might have if the objectId between [GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET) and viewer are inconsistent? Currently, there are two workflows that we're interested in as the below. Could you kindly point out which one your workflow is?

- Normal workflow ([GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET) -> Viewer), e.g., get dbIds(objectIds) by filtering properties with some conditions with [GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET), then partial load objects with LMV.
- Reverse workflow (Viewer -> [GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET)), e.g., select some objects in LMV, then post back to [GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET) to get specific properties to store in DB.

**Note.** If the information you want to share cannot be posted publicly, please send it to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com` instead. Meanwhile, please remove any confidential information and personal data from anything you want to share with us before sending it out.

**Update 2021/07/21**

Just to let future devs know that SVF2 is now GA, article is [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready).

Comment: Hi Eason, we upload the model and translate, I then use one of the metadata/property endpoints to map the nodeId's to rows in our database. In the model viewer, we can select a node by selecting a row in our own table OR we can click a node in the model to filter our data table. Does that answer your question? I email support yesterday :)

Comment: We have reverted back to using SVF format in the viewer for now.

Comment: Btw. here's a temporary workaround until the SVF1/SVF2 dbid mapping is provided by the Model Derivative service: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids.

Comment: @PetrBroz I missed this comment and haven't tried it, as SVF2 is now GA i'll give it a try again.